# How to connect jmeter with database by using mysql-connector-java?

Tags: mysql, testing, jmeter, automated-tests, database-testing

I am using phpMyAdmin version 5.7.15 and database mysql-connector-java version 5.1.40, but I am unable to connect the database with jmeter3.0. Could you please advise?

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your driver in jmeter/lib folder

Then add a [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) and fill in:

- Database URL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html
- JDBC Driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
- login and password
- Variable Name will identify the connection

Then add a [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) under a [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

and fill in:

- Variable Name : same value as the one in JDBC Connection Configuration
- The other fields which depend on what you want to do

Read this tutorial:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) will help you.